# Use Google Search as Google Chrome's spell checker

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, spell-check, google-search

I think that the Google Chrome spell checker is terrible.  I know that Google (the search engine) has a superb spell checker for users who submit queries into [its search engine](http://goo.gl/n2QcE).

Is there any way to run misspelled words through [Google.com](http://goo.gl/n2QcE) and have the list of possible alternatives be the search suggestions?

Are there other web dictionaries I could use instead of the default for [Google Chrome](http://goo.gl/ZoDqh)?

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Google+Chrome+spell+checker+sucks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can now use a smarter spellchecking function by sending the text that we type into the browser to Google's servers. This allows Chrome to use the same [spellchecking technology](https://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1723) as Google search. To enable this feature, **right-click** a misspelled word, hover over **Spell-Checker Options** and select **Ask Google for Suggestion**.

[image]

I believe new installations of [Chrome](https://google.com/chrome) come with this feature enabled by default. You can always choose to disable it by clicking the spanner icon [image] and selecting **Settings** > **Show advanced settings** > **Privacy** section.

You can read the finer details of how [Google](https://google.com) treats your information that you provide to [Google Chrome](https://google.com/chrome) in their [Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en-GB/privacy.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try the [After the Deadline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho?hc=search&hcp=main) extension for Chrome.

> After the Deadline uses artificial intelligence to check spelling, style, and grammar. Use it to check your tweets, find mistakes in your email, and socialize with confidence. Click the ABC icon in the lower-right corner of an editable area to proofread your writing.

[image]

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It has a much better dictionary and will spell check?

Comment: I'm looking to use the Google search engine as a dictionary

Comment: Quote "Is there another great dictionary I could use instead of the default for Google Chrome?"

Comment: I think by *another great dictionary*, he meant a `.bdic` file to put in the `Dictionaries` directory as opposed to an extension (and its associated burdens).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do what you want, and I doubt that they will implement it anytime soon.

Further, there are few alternative dictionaries because even though it is an [open format](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries) and based on another open format, it is a relatively new one and it seems nobody has bothered to make their own (ironically implying that the default one is good enough).

Your best bet is to [submit a feature-request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) and cross your fingers.

Comment: Thanks.  I think thats the most honest answer, (also one that I wanted to hear)... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Grammarly for spelling and simple grammar correction and it works well with chrome. Maybe it will help you too.

[grammarly.com](http://grammarly.com)

Comment: Grammarly sends all text you type to themselves. It's a keylogger. https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/1104132995026317312